# ¿Como serializar objetos a una base de datos en Java?

Tags: java, data

Buenas! soy nuevo aquí y tenia una duda, en Java, si quiero serializar un objeto (por ejemplo, un objeto mapa, que tiene dentro 3 enteros y un array de objetos) ¿Cómo puedo guardar eso en una base de datos? He conseguido serializar el objeto y guardarlo en firebird usando serializable, pero no consigo extraer los datos de la tabla

Comment: QUe problema concreto tienes? Si sabes serializar (y deserializar) el objeto hacia un archivo, entonces deberias poder hacerlo con una base de datos, siemplemente lo guarsdas como un tipo binario.

Comment: Deserializar es el problema, no sé sacar el objeto de la base de datos, en la base de datos está como tipo "Blob"

Comment: Sabes guardar y recupera un array de bytes cualquiera a un blob? Probaste hacerlo?

Comment: Si, he llegado hasta el punto de sacar un array de Bytes, pero no sé pasar eso a un objeto propio, he intentado con una libreria deserializadora, pero no lo consigo

Comment: REpito la pregunta inicial: sabes deserializar un objeto cualquiera (por ejemplo, desed un archivo)?  Quizas ayude que copies tu codigo.

Comment: JDBC, JPA, Hibernate... busca tutoriales, mira como funciona, y cuando tengas una pregunta específica escríbela en este foro. Por favor revisa [help] y [ask].

Comment: Para serializar/deserializar entre objetos de clases implementando `Serializable` y arreglos de `byte` usas  `ObjectOutputStream` con `ByteArrayOutputStream` para serializar y `ObjectInputStream`  con  `ByteArrayInputStream` para deserializar. Si necesitas un ejemplo concreto sería bueno si podrías las partes de código que manejas (definición de tu clase, tu DAO etc.). Saludos.